# Ruby Savon How to set verify_callback

Tags: ruby, soap, savon

I'm doing soap requests on devices that have self signed certs. I set verify_mode :none, but I still get "at depth 0 - 18: self signed certificate" warnings. I know if I can set the verify_callback, I can suppress these warnings.

Can anyone tell me how to set the verify_callback in Savon? I have tried:

```
client.http.auth.ssl.verify_callback = lambda (|arg1, arg2| true)
```

and

```
client.http.ssl_config.verify_callback = lambda (|arg1, arg2| true)
```

Both return no method errors.

I have seen this option set in soap4r calls, so I know it works. I just want to know if I can set it in Savon as well.

Answer (score 0):

Any chance it's  resolved in savon 2? It was recently updated http://savonrb.com/version2.html

An ssl specific issue was also recently resolved: https://github.com/savonrb/savon/issues/344